# Android databinding generated class with wrong member type

Tags: android, binding, kotlin

I'm new to DataBinding, and I've been trying to set up binding to a sample app based on the [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions). However, when I created separate subfolder called "Data" put my User class in it and tried to run it, I got an error "Cannot access class 'Data.User'". I'd like to separate my classes in different folders (i.e. make MVVM structure)

My activity code:

```
package kozak.databindingtesting

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import kozak.databindingtesting.Data.User
import kozak.databindingtesting.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val user = User("Marcin")
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.user = user
}
```

}

User class:

```
package kozak.databindingtesting.Data;

public class User {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name;

    public User(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

}
```

Activity layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="kozak.databindingtesting.Data.User"/>
    </data>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_constraint_layout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.name}"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVhs2.png)

When I just paste this class out to general folder it works fine.
I have android.databinding.enableV2=true in gradle.properties, as well as enabled properly dataBinding in gradle.build - as mentioned, this example worked fine on its own.

P.S. Please ignore the fragment class, it is currently omitted

Comment: Can you post the User class code?

Comment: There you go.  Plain and simple